# How to create random sample proportional to vector in R?

Tags: r, random, sample

Assume the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:6, value=c(10,20,10,20,30,10))

df

  id value
1  1    10
2  2    20
3  3    10
4  4    20
5  5    30
6  6    10
```

I want to randomly assign every individual to one of three groups (A,B,C). I want to achieve given proportions of 30% to be in group A, 50% to be in group B, 20% to be in group C. But I want to do this assignment based on the value column. In other words, I want to achieve something like the following:

```
  id value group
1  1    10     A
2  2    20     A
3  3    10     C
4  4    20     B
5  5    30     B
6  6    10     C
```

or...

```
  id value group
1  1    10     A
2  2    20     B
3  3    10     A
4  4    20     C
5  5    30     B
6  6    10     A
```

Of course, in this example, these are perfect solutions. But the random assignment should approach a group assignment as close to the given proportions as possible. So another example would be the following:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:6, value=c(112,56,53,13,80,120))

df

  id value
1  1   112
2  2    56
3  3    53
4  4    13
5  5    80
6  6   120
```

One possible assignment could be:

```
  id value group
1  1   112     B
2  2    56     A
3  3    53     C
4  4    13     C    
5  5    80     A
6  6   120     B
```

In this case, the assignment wouldn't be perfect but close to the desired proportions (group A: 31.3%, group B: 53.4%, group C: 15.2%).

Is there any way to achieve this in R? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand this. If your frame was 100 rows long, would the sum of the value column still be 100 (as it sums to 100 in this example)?

Comment: is `value` guaranteed to always be a whole number, or not necessarily?

Comment: No, this was only an example to make the proportions more obvious. This could be any number. But in general, the point is that the values in the value column in the corresponding groups correspond as closely as possible to the desired proportions. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I think what you're asking for is random sampling with a tolerance. For instance, if a sample is produces and the sum-of-square differences between the desired proportions and the proportions of `sum(value)` by-group is within some-value, it's good, otherwise sample again. To me this sounds like an under-constrained problem as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your goal as, after group assignment, you want `sum(value[group == "A"]) / sum(value)` to approximately equal `0.3`, and likewise with `"B"` (`0.5`) and `"C"` (`0.2`). If that's the case, all you have to do is assign groups with those probability weights, without doing anything special to take `value` into account at all. The sums of `value` will (on average) shake out as you want as a natural consequence of the randomization. Look:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)

# 100-row example dataframe
df <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  value = sample(1:200, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# simulate 100 sets of group assignments
sims <- map_dfr(
  1:100,                              # iterate 100x
  ~ df %>% 
    mutate(group = sample(
      c("A", "B", "C"), 
      size = 100, 
      replace = TRUE, 
      prob = c(.3, .5, .2))           # probability weights
    ) %>% 
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarize(prop = sum(value)) %>%  # compute `value` proportion
    mutate(prop = prop / sum(prop))   # within each group
)

# central tendency & dispersion across simulations
sims %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(across(
    prop, 
    list(mean, sd, median, ~ quantile(.x, .25), ~ quantile(.x, .75))
  ))
```

| Group | Mean (SD) | Median (IQR) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | .29 (.06) | .29 (.25 - .32) |
| B | .51 (.06) | .50 (.47 - .55) |
| C | .21 (.04) | .21 (.18 - .23) |

```
# distribution of proportions across sims by groups
samps %>% 
  ggplot(aes(prop)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = group), alpha = .75) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image]